# Webfaction: How do I run a Static/Perl app and Django app under the same website

Tags: django

I have an existing Perl app that I'm moving to a Webfaction website. I will be adding Django apps to this Webfaction website too.

I would like the Django app to get first call and so would want its URL path to be /

This would allow me to add any new URLs to the urls.py I wish as my app grows.

If the URL doesn't match anything in the urls.py I would like it to get passed to the static Perl app.

For example

- /app1  -> Django
- /app2  -> Django

Everything else not picked up by urls.py I would want going to my Perl app

For example:

- /index.html  ->  Static/Perl app
- /about.html  ->  Static/Perl app
- /contact.html  ->  Static/Perl app
- /apps/perlapp1.cgi  ->  Static/Perl app

etc

How do I go about achieving this in Webfaction?

Answer (score 1):

The largest benefit of using a static app for the static pages (and not rendering them using simple views/templates using django) is the performance gain by not involving django at all in this request. but if you let django run and look through all the urls for a match, and only render static if there's not match, you're not getting that benefit.

I use /static/ as a location for the static app and / for django. so every request starting with /static/ skips the django server. whenever I want to link to static content I just add /static/ to it.

Comment: The problem is I can't change the URLs of my existing website. Users will complain if they can't get to all the existing urls when I move over to Webfaction.

Comment: How about adding a permanent redirect from those urls from their current_location to /static/current_location using djnago? (maybe even for each 404 - try to redirect to /staic/request.path).

Answer (score 1):

Well, Webfaction makes this very easy! In your control panel, go to "websites", edit (or create) the website, and in the process there add any number of new (or existing) apps. You can map those apps any way you like. But note that for the first app you will be adding you won't have a choice (it will be mapped to "/"), but for additional apps you can specify your own path.

**Create or edit a website:**

[image]

**Add the first application:**

[image]

**Add additional applications** (note: now there is a URL option):

[image]

**The result:**

[image]

Hit Save and you're done.